# Passing parameters from AsyncTask to an method

Tags: android, parameter-passing, android-alertdialog

I am using an onClick on an image to run an AlertDialog.
The onClick is set in an AsyncTask's onPostExecute.

```
ImageView image = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
            image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_action_discard);
            image.setId(n);
            image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    showpopup();
                }
            });
```

When the dialog is being showed, and the user presses the positive button i need to run a query with the ID of the image..

How can i get the Id of the image in the following class;

```
public void showpopup() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle(getString(R.string.Alertdialognl1))
            .setMessage(getString(R.string.Alertdialognl2))
            .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.Alertdialognlja),
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface Dialog,
                                int which) {
                            Log.i("positive", "clicked");
                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.Alertdialognlnee),
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface Dialog,
                                int which) {
                            Log.i("negative", "clicked");
                        }
                    }).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the id into showPopup as a final int

```
public void showPopup(final int id) {
...
.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.Alertdialognlja),
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface Dialog,
                            int which) {
                        Log.i("positive", "clicked with id: " + id);

                    }
                })
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
public void onClick(View v)
```

to

```
public void onClick(final View v)
```

This will let you access the clicked view inside the dialog button's `onClickListener`.

Also

```
showpopup() 
public void showpopup()
```

to

```
showpopup(v)
public void showpopup(View V)
```

*PS:Typecast the `View v` inside the `showpopup()` into an `ImageView`* and use `v.getId();`

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to create the AsyncTask subclass that and store the Id in that class. Then just store the id in the asynctask subclass as an instance variable and create an instance of the asynctask subclass in the activity and create a getter for the Id.